# Multiple images in slide show

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I want to have a different kind of slide show. I tried bootstrap carousel and so many other slide shows, but they contain only one picture and my issue is that i want to have multiple photos.

[image]

Is there any slide show or any idea that causes a slide show like this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a special thing just use this css:

```
.swipe{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and in your html:

```
<div class=swipe>
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

In computers it has a scroll bar but in mobile you can swipe it

Comment: let me try that with my mobile

Comment: Thanx I never thout that the answer is easy this much! thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? (It uses a horizontal `overflow`, allowing movement from side to side)

```css
.slide-container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx I never thout that the answer is easy this much! thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://swiperjs.com/ and initiate using slidesPerView. You can to define slidesPerView for each breakpoint too. This way:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Default parameters
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
})
```